# Read through a concatenated file in python

Tags: python, file

I have a file (`merged-control.txt`) where I concatenated contents of other files into. It has over 10000 files merged, and the structure looks like this:

```
control-part1.txt
1  10      12
1  34      44
2   1      -3
3   4     -10.3
3   3.390   4
4  43       3
control-part2.txt
1 -90.3     2
2  32       3
3  43     -20
4   2       2
```

Before I was reading each file `(control-part1.txt, control-part2.txt, ...)` separately (they are in the same folder), and I was using:

```
filePath = "/path/to/control/files"
file_counter = 0
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(filePath, 'control*.txt')):
    file_counter += 1
    #print filename 
    shortname = filename.strip().split('/')[-1]
    types = shortname.strip().split('-')[0]
    print types
    numbers_table=open(filename,'r')
    for line in numbers_table:
        print line
        indexes = line[0].strip()
        firsts = line[1].strip()
        seconds = line[2].strip()
```

Since it got complicated to store ~10000 files in the same folder, I merged them.

I tried to split the lines with `partition`:

```
with open('merged-control.txt') as f:
    chunks = []
    for line in f:
        chunk = line.strip().partition("control")
        print chunk[0]
        chunks.append(chunk)
    print chunks
```

And it gives:

```
1  10      12
1  34      44
2   1      -3
3   4     -10.3
3   3.390   4
4  43       3

1 -90.3     2
2  32       3
3  43     -20
4   2       2
[('', 'control', '-part1.txt'), ('1  10      12', '', ''), ('1  34      44', '', ''), ('2   1      -3', '', ''), ('3   4     -10.3', '', ''), ('3   3.390   4', '', ''), ('4  43       3', '', ''), ('', 'control', '-part2.txt'), ('1 -90.3     2', '', ''), ('2  32       3', '', ''), ('3  43     -20', '', ''), ('4   2       2', '', '')]
```

Now the files are not separated from each other, and I cannot reach to index, first column and second column of each file.

How can I read each file when they are in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you already have all the data stored in chunks.  Your last line "print chunks" shows that.  Because you've concatenated all your raw data files into a single file for the sake of file manageability this approach has placed all your data into a single chunky variable.

Its a bit awkward, but you could use what you already have to access and index everything.  Try something like this:

```
for c in chunks:
 if c[2] != '': print c[2]
 else:
  theData = c[0].split()
  print theData
```